# found v did find

Tags: grammar

The conversation worked like this:

Bill went to New York in 2002 to find his father.

Did he find his father?

My answer was:
Yes he did find his father.

The questioner asked why I used 'did find' instead of found. Was I wrong to use 'did find'? And if I was wrong could someone explain why. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Did find* is emphatic, or contrastive.

Using the emphatic *did find* here has an implication of "contrary to what you might have expected, he found him". *Found* would be equally good, but without that implication.

Comment: True. However, I wonder how much this answer would help a beginner or a non-native speaker of English. We are on ELU not ELL.

Answer (score -1):

> Did he find his father?

I simply write an answer of this question : -

> Yes , he did.

else you have written right answer in your second paragraph that preferable.

> Yes, he found him / his father.